# Applying velocity to objects in a specified direction

Tags: c++, physics

How to apply velocity to a particular direction?

Data which I have:

1. object position (P1)
2. destination (P2)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Velocity is speed and direction, and the only tricky part is the direction.  Your question cuts right to that problem.  This kind of vector math is [linear algebra 101](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra).   However, since Wikipedia offers its usual incomprehensible notation for otherwise simple mathematics, here's a quick summary.

The vector from `P1` to `P2` can be found by subtracting:

```
v = [(P2.x - P1.x), (P2.y - P1.y), (P2.z - P1.z)];
```

For directions, it is very likely you want a unit vector (length = 1), so that you can apply more trigonometry to it (not so in this case, but it will be useful regardless).

Getting a vector's unit is easy; divide its components by its length:

```
vLength = sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z);  // a scalar value
vUnit = [(v.x / vLength), (v.y / vLength), v.z / vLength)];
```

Now that you have a vector of length one, you can give your object a speed value, and move it in any direction at constant (or not constant) speed:

```
objVelocity = [(vUnit.x * speed), (vUnit.y * speed), (vUnit.z * speed)];
```

---

Hopefully this is easy to translate to C++ using whatever library you choose.